# AJAX send data to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

send `$username` php with `data:  new FormData(this),` to add.php like `data:  new FormData(this),$username` how can i do it with ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#uploadFormuserimg").on('submit',(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "add.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#user_img_a").html(data);
                },
                error: function() 
                { alert("error");
                }           
            });
        }));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: The code shown is pretty much how you'd make an AJAX request.  How specifically is this failing?  When you debug this, where exactly does it go wrong?

Comment: This part of the code. I just want to send more data `data:  new FormData(this),` to add.php

Comment: @mody: Yes, you've already stated what you want to do.  What you haven't done is describe what isn't working.  If there's no problem to describe, there's no way for us to help solve the problem.  Because there isn't a problem.

Comment: @David : There is no problem, I just want to add some data for sending to side_server(add.php)

Comment: Please answer the questions asked in comments and we might be able to provide answers.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myData = new FormData(this);
    myData.append('username','<?php echo $username; ?>');
```

and get on "add.php" like this

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

This worked on my side.

Comment: like another values of form

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments to the question, specifically:

> I just want to add some data

Are you just asking how to add more fields to the object that was created already in the `data` value?  Something like this:

```
var myData = new FormData(this);
myData.append("anotherField", "anotherValue");
// etc.
```

Then just use that variable as your AJAX data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "add.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:  myData,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        $("#user_img_a").html(data);
    },
    error: function() 
    { alert("error");
    }           
});
```

You can store anything you like in a variable and use that variable at a later time.  [With a `FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) you would generally use `.append()` to add more key/value pairs to it.

Comment: ok the another value is php code i can use like this : `myData.anotherField = "<?php echo $username ?>";`  ????

Comment: @mody: Sure.  PHP doesn't care whether you surround an `echo` with HTML code or JavaScript code, it's all text as far as PHP is concerned.  Did you try?

Comment: i get error in side_server(add.php) shown (Notice: Undefined variable: username in  add.php) it is the way to get variable `$username`  from side_server ????

Comment: @mody: Well, if you haven't defined the variable `$username` then you can't *use* the variable `$username`.  A variable has to exist before you can use it.